# Hibernate schema validation fails with MySQL CHAR mapped to String

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

When using the Hibernate validator to verify that JPA entities match the database schema (typically be setting `hibernate.ddl-auto = verify`) it will fail when it encounters a MySQL `CHAR` that has been mapped to a `String` field.

For example, this MySQL table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `item` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` char(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

May be mapped to a JPA entity like this:

```
@Entity
public class Item
{
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;
}
```

The verification process will fail with the following exception:

> **org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException:**
>   Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [name] in
>   table [item]; found [char (Types#CHAR)], but expecting [varchar(255)
>   (Types#VARCHAR)]

A typical solution to this is to use the Hibernate `@Type` annotation on the field to specify the column data type, this works well enough to satisfy the validator:

```
@Column
@Type(type = "char")
private String name;
```

When you actually issue a query that requires mapping a ResultSet to the entity, you will encounter a different set of exceptions (in this case Spring Data was used to issue the query):

> **org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException:** Could not set field
>   value [B] value by reflection : [class com.example.Item.name] setter
>   of com.example.Item.name; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set field value [B]
>   value by reflection : [class com.example.Item.name] setter of
>   com.example.Item.name

and

> **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:** Can not set java.lang.String field com.example.Item.name to java.lang.Character

Comment: Do not use `char` type in MySQL... Most of the time it is mapped to `varchar` anyway, but confuses tools like JPA/Hibernate...

Comment: Also a column of `char(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` is using 200 bytes per row, as "utf8mb4" takes up to 4 bytes per chars... See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto That's great in an ideal world but sometimes you're working with a legacy schema that you have no control over which uses `char` so you need to compromise.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The solution to these exceptions is to set the column definition in the actual JPA `@Column` annotation rather than the Hibernate specific `@Type` annotation:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "char")
private String name;
```

This will satisfy the Hibernate validator without confusing Hibernate into thinking you're actually mapping a Character field.